# What is the fastest way to increase my mail quota?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We are using Google App Script tied to a Google Sheet. We use doPost to add form data to the Sheet and GmailApp.sendEmail to send email notifications to the people who need to be notified. Unfortunately, we hit our daily quota far faster than we were expecting and now I need to know the fastest way to boost our quota.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and the faster, the better.

Thanks, all.

Comment: Sounds like you need a paid-for solution at scale? What options have you researched for this project? If you're hitting a quota with your current choice, it's unlikely you can just increase it with the click of a button, otherwise it wouldn't have been set there in the first place.

Comment: First of all you need to know which [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) you hit. Then you can think about how to optimize your code to not hit this quota or consider upgrading your account to obtain more quota.

Answer (score 1):

Quotas are set at different levels for users of consumer accounts (such as gmail.com) and different G Suite/Google Workspace editions.
Daily quotas are refreshed at the end of a 24-hour window; the exact time of this refresh, however, varies between users.

Here’s a reference for the email sending quota limit using Apps Script:

[Email API Quota Limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG0vV.png)

[References]

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas
https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

You can also check your daily email quota limit using [getRemainingDailyQuota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=en#getRemainingDailyQuota()) method in MailApp Class:

```
var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
Logger.log("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
```

If you're already using a paid subscription and still met the email quota limit, then it would be best for you to look for an email campaign services that will allow you to send more than the specified email quota limit provided by Google Workspace